# Unexpected value error in Kendo Bootatrap theme file

Tags: css

I have this line in an official Telerik Kendo Bootstrap theme:

```css
.k-imageeditor-canvas {
    ...
    background-position: 0 0, calc(10px / 2) calc(10px / 2);
    ...
}
```

The error shows up as: `Unexpected Value` with the red squiggly line under the `calc(10px / 2) calc(10px / 2)`

It's not a show-stopper, but I just wanted to figure out how to define this.

Comment: Seems like a valid value for the rule set. Did you see anything warnings in your dev tools or browser console?

Comment: Does this cause any _actual_ error, or is the problem limited to "my IDE shows a red wavy line below it"?

Comment: @Rob, I have the actual code as text up there already. I wanted to show the error part.

Comment: @CBroe No actual errors. Just figuring out if there id a syntax error or IDE is not recognizing properly

Comment: some of the IDE are not always up to date with new syntax so they can show you error for valid syntaxes